# Как создать правильный href для а tag-а?

Tags: php, html, mvc

Например моя текущая страница  `aaa.ru/gallery/albums`

В навигационном баре у меня есть  `(a href ="abc" ) profile (/a)`

когда нажимаю на `profile` адрес моей страницы меняется на `aaa.ru/gallery/abc`

как сделать чтобы при нажатии на `profile` адрес менялся на `aaa.ru/abc` ?

Comment: `/abc`. Почитайте о абсолютных и относительных ссылках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы понять суть вам лучше поискать об адресации в unix-системах

Если в кратце, то ссылка «внутрь» этого каталога выглядит как `./abc` или просто `abc`.

Ссылка на «уровень выше» выглядит как `../abc`.

Ну, соответственно, если начать с корня, то и ссылки должны быть такие: `/abc`.